# 2007 RAV4 Transfer Case: Making the Impossible Possible?

Tags: toyota, rav4, transfer-case

2007 RAV4 Sport 3.5 6L AWD transfer case is cracked. Is it possible to remove/replace the transfer case WITHOUT pulling the engine/trans?
Supposedly most of the 3.5L engine AWD such as Sienna, Highlander, etc can have the transfer case removed by cutting off one of the case mounting bolt.

Anyone know if this is true of the RAV 3.5? If you have done this, got any tips?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!